# How to avoid closing drawer when navigating to different screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have integrated react-navigation-drawer to add drawer navigation. From Landing screen when I open drawer, my drawer closes automatically when I navigate to a different screen. This is the default behavior of drawer.
My requirement is when I perform the following:
Landing screen -> Open Drawer-> Screen 1 -> Back to Landing Screen
then, I should see the drawer open.
I have used the following versions in my code:

"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.2",

Can Anyone help me with this?
P.S. I have tried maintaining state and manually opening drawer on back press. But it does not seem natural. Rather, one can figure out easily that the drawer is forcibly opened.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the route structure to achieve this. Previously, I added a whole stack of screens in my drawer navigator.
Now I changed the structure. I set only one Home Screen inside my Drawer navigator instead of whole screen stack.
Through this I can achieve such behaviour.